# Запись элементов в массив.

Tags: jquery, html, css

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь выполнить такой момент. 
Мне нужно записать в массив значение value и name у ИНПУТА. 
Конструкция должна быть такой.

> var mas = ("black" => "Черный","brown"
> => "Бурый","white" => "Белый" ).

Вот сам див с инпутами.

```
 <div class="bl_choiceOfColor">
<input class="active" type="submit" value="Черный" name="black" status="opend">
<input type="submit" value="Бурый" name="brown" status="closed">
<input type="submit" value="Белый" name="white" status="closed">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Вот сам скрипт который я пишу.

```
var COLOR_prod = []; 
                     $(".bl_choiceOfColor input").each(function(i){ 
                         var that = $(this);
                         if(that.hasClass("active")){
                             COLOR_prod[i] = that.attr("name");
                             }
                      });
```

Значения записываются только как записать в место ключей значения value/

Answer (score 4):

используйте не массив, а обычный хэш:

```
var COLOR_prod = {}; 
$('.bl_choiceOfColor').find('input').each(function(){ 
     var that = $(this);
     if(that.hasClass("active")){
           // var mas = ("black" => "Черный","brown" => "Бурый","white" => "Белый" ).
           COLOR_prod[this.name] = this.value;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то, [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) уже все ответил, но как альтернатива:

```
var COLOR_prod = {};
$('.bl_choiceOfColor .active').map(function(){
    return COLOR_prod[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
console.log(COLOR_prod);
```